# how to change fragment inside a dialogfragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to make an empty `DialogFragment` with a `LinearLayout` and then change fragments inside the `LinearLayout`. For example, a login where the first fragment is 3 button (facebook, google+, email login) and when somebody pressed email then the 2. fragment has a layout with `EditTexts` if Google or Facebook was pressed then the other fragment appears with a `ProgressBar`.

this is my empty dialog layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/testFragmentController"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"></LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the first fragment's code (I am using android annotations):

```
@EFragment(R.layout.dialog)
public class FragmentGeneralDialog extends ClickDialogFragment {

    @ViewById
    LinearLayout testFragmentController;


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        this.setStyle(R.style.Dialog_No_Border, getTheme());

        return dialog;
    }


    @AfterViews
    void afterViews() {
        loadActivity();
        GlobalData.setFragmentContainer(testFragmentController);
        activity.loadMenuFragment(FragmentSocialDialog_.class, new SlideLeftAnimation());

    }


}
```

`loadMenuFragments(...)` is this:

```
public <T extends Fragment> T loadMenuFragment(final Class<T> cls,
                                                   final IAnimation a) {
        T fragment = null;
        try {
            fragment = cls.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Fragment " + cls.toString()
                    + " has no empty constructor");
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if (a != null) {
            transaction.setCustomAnimations(a.getInId(), a.getOutId(), a.getInId(),
                    a.getOutId());
        }

        transaction.replace(R.id.testFragmentController, fragment);

        try {
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return fragment;
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to get the `childFragmentManager` from the dialogfragment [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()), then from the child fragments you can change the fragments via `getParentFragment().getChildFragmentManager()`

Answer (score 1):

I found a better way than `getParentFragment`. You can in parent fragment add `public static FragmentManager` and use it in nested fragment:

In parent:

```
public class SelectProductDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
public static FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_product,container,false);
    fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
    return v;
}
}
```

In child: for example for replace transaction:

```
ProductsGridFragment productsGridFragment = new ProductsGridFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = SelectProductDialogFragment.fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.dialog_order_container,productsGridFragment)
                            .addToBackStack(null);

                    transaction.commit();
```