# Fragment inside a DialogFragment, blank screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have a dialog fragment(FragmentA), with a frame layout.
I am trying to add another fragment(FragmentB) into the frame layout.

```
public void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_canvas, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Just to confirm, I am logging inside OnCreateView of FragmentB, and it gets printed when call setFragment.

But the view of FragmentA doesn't add FragmentB into the frame layout.

Edit:

FragmentA is actually a `DialogFragment`. Can that be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried using `commitNow`, or `commit` followed by `getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()` ?

Comment: Tried this, Didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried 
`FragmentTransaction transaction = 
              getParentFragment().getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();`
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475556/how-to-change-fragment-inside-a-dialogfragment)

Comment: I am calling this from FragmentA, so getParentFragment is invalid. Here FragmentA is parent of FragmentB

Answer (score 1):

Use this I think it will works.
 If you on Fragment A than use code like below

```
    Fragment fr = new FragmentB();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fr);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

if you are on activity from where you call fragment B than use Code like below `

```
  Fragment fr = new FragmentB();
  FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
  ft.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fr);
  ft.commit();`
```

// xml

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/general_home_toolbar">
```

Comment: Mine is the first case. But throws error, `No view found for id 0x7f08006f .... for FragmentB`.

Comment: give your framelayout id when replace fragment

Comment: No, thats okay, I used my i.d. accordingly